# Aborted Core Dumped

Tags: c

```
stack.out: malloc.c:2372: 
sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1)- 1) * 2])) - 
__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) 
    && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) 
    && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I was dealing with my codes that includes stack subject,and suddenly it is seen my gcc compiler's error I did not get anything,What does it mean,if you know these things,please tell my wrong in the program.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who is supposed to read that mess? At least format the message, provide a [mcve] and all required information. Read [ask] for details.

Comment: @Olaf Take it up with the FSF. ;-)  That appears to be an [error message emitted by glibc](https://www.google.com/search?q=malloc.c%3A2372) when heap memory gets corrupted.  It's a bit unfair to drop that "error message" on a new coder...

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I was mostly after not even using code formatting. It was hard to see where the message originates from before the edit. Too bad it was not OP; such edits should be required to be done by the author; at least that shows he is interested in getting an answer. But as he does not add the required information, I assume he is not.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have corrupted heap memory, probably because you wrote well past the end of some malloc()'d memory. Use gdb to get a traceback of your function calls, and they may help you debug it. To get a traceback of your program, assuming it is called myProg, type the following:

```
gdb myProg
run
```

after it gets this exception, type:

```
bt
```

Because you are likely trampling memory, where the error occurred may not be a part of this traceback stack, but it is a good place to start. If this does not help, then use either `valgrind` or `memwatch`, both are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43025916/6693299) and these tools will tell you where you are writing past the end of memory, resulting in the corruption, and the core dump.